# One button connected to two different event methods in PyQT

Tags: pyqt

I'm using PyQT4 to create a GUI. I have a button that needs to connect with one `def` when a certain condition is met. If this condition is not met, then the button should connect to another `def`. So far this is what I have -

```
    if self.txtAgilent.text() and self.txtBattery.text():
        self.connect(self.buttonPlot, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.plotButtonClicked)
    else:
        self.connect(self.buttonPlot, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.fileErrorMsgBox)
```

As above, if the first condition is met (i.e. if two files are selected), a plot is created. If not, an error message box pops up. The problem right now is that whenever I hit the plot button on my GUI, only the error message box pops up even after I have selected two files successfully.

The message box function is as follow:

```
def fileErrorMsgBox(self):
    w = QWidget()
    msg = QMessageBox.warning(w, "WARNING", "File(s) not chosen! Please choose a file.")
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by selected, all i can see is you trying to get the value of two text fields by calling `.text()`

Comment: @danidee. I think the OP means that the user must populate the two text fields by selecting (i.e. choosing) files.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is not to try and change the method the button is connected to. Instead, keep the button connected to the same method, and **within** that method, performs the check (whether things are selected or appropriate text is in text boxes, whatever your use case).

So, for example, something like:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.connect(self.buttonPlot, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.plotButtonClicked)

def plotButtonClicked(self):
    if self.txtAgilent.text() and self.txtBattery.text():
        # do what plotButtonClicked did before
    else:
        # create and show the error message box
```

Note, you should really be using the [new style signals/slot API](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) in PyQt which performs connections like this:

```
self.buttonPlot.clicked.connect(self.plotButtonClicked)
```